# Pronúncia da palavra "sintaxe"

Tags: pronúncia

Qual ou quais são as pronúncias corretas ou aceitáveis da palavra "*sintaxe*" ?

Já ouvi diferentes pronúncias da palavra *sintaxe*, variando a forma como a primeira(1) sílaba "*xe*" é pronunciada, e também variações na sílaba tônica, ora como paroxítona ora como proparoxítona.

Já que as pronúncias como proparoxítonas são incompatíveis com sua ortografia, pois não há um acento na terceira sílaba "*sin*", acredito que estas pronúncias podem ser anglicismo da pronúncia da sua tradução em inglês *syntax*, e portanto são incorretas.

À seguir algumas adaptações de já ouvi, incluindo as versões proparoxítonas (sílabas tônicas destacadas em maiúsculas e negrito):

- sin-**TAS**-se
- sin-**TA**-cse
- **SIN**-tas-se
- **SIN**-ta-cse

---

(1) *Método de contagem das sílabas:* direita para esquerda

Comment: "variando a forma como a primeira sílaba "xe" é pronunciada,..."   a primeira sílaba "xe"?    ???

Comment: Contagem das sílabas da direita para a esquerda. Primeira sílaba tônica é oxítona, segunda sílaba tônica paroxítona, terceira proparoxítona (as demais não me lembro de serem numeradas)

Comment: As sílabas são contadas da esquerda para a direita. Quando o acento tônico cai na última sílaba, a palavra é oxítona. Se cai na penúltima, ela é paroxítona.  Se cai na antepenúltima, ela é proparoxítona.

Comment: @Romildo: Você pode denominar ou contar as sílabas como preferir, apenas deixe claro para que as pessoas saibam localizar a sílaba que você denominou de primeira ou última, por exemplo. No meu caso usei a contagem da direita para a esquerda, então usar qualquer outra forma de contagem diferente da que usei, não funcionará. A contagem que usei: https://www.educacao.cc/lingua-portuguesa/silabas-tonicas-oxitonas-paroxitonas-e-proparoxitonas/

Comment: @Luciano  É a forma como aquele site conta as sílabas para classificar uma palavra quanto a sua sílaba tônica.  O fato de o autor explicar que está contando da direita para a esquerda já mostra que é uma exclusividade desse tópico da gramática.  Não é o modo como os professores falam em sala de aula quando estão ensinando divisão de sílabas e número de sílabas das palavras etc.  É bom que fique claro.  Não há como ensinar o que é uma palavra paroxítona ou proparoxítona sem contar da direita para a esquerda.  Mas essa forma de identificar uma sílaba começa e termina nesse tópico.

Comment: @Centaurus Tenho a impressão que os professores de português para estrangeiros preferem enumerar as sílabas como first, second and third da direita para a esquerda, ao explicar acentuação da língua portuguesa em inglês. Não tenho estatísticas é só um observação pessoal. No final das contas tanto faz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambas as pronúncias para o `x` são corretas, como consta, e.g., [nesse dicionário](http://www.aulete.com.br/sintaxe):

> (sin.ta.xe) [ss ou cs]

Como a pronúncia `cs` sendo aparentemente mais comum no Brasil e `ss` em Portugal.

Com relação à tonicidade, de fato a palavra [não pode ser proparoxítona](https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-proparoxitonas/) por não ser acentuada, com o erro de prosódia sendo um provável anglicismo, como o que ocorre com as palavras 'Nobel' e 'recorde'.

Comment: Depende da região? P/ mim sempre foi algo como "sin-TÁ-kice"

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a forma mais correta de pronunciar a palavra `sintaxe`, seja

> 'sin-TA-cse'

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o dicionário [Michaelis On-line](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/sintaxe/), a pronúncia do "x" na palavra é dada pelo som de "ss".

> sin·ta·xe
>   (ss)

Answer (score 1):

A pronúncia mais antiga é sim-tá-se.

Devido ao facto de "ks" ser uma pronúncia comum para o "x", especialmente no inglês, a pronúncia "sintáks" tem-se disseminado.

https://dicionario.priberam.org/sintaxe
https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa-aao/sintaxe
https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pronuncia-do-x-xenofobia-e-sintaxe/9650